# Android LoadScreen

Tags: android, optimization, startup, splash-screen

When my app launches a file **scraper** that iterates recursively through the sdcard is kicked off.  As you can imagine, this takes a fair amount of time.  On my epad transformer it can take 30 to 40 seconds to blitz through the 32gb of storage.

This activity is done in two fragments that live on the main layout, launched from the main activity.

Obviously with load times like that I need to do something to alert the user.  However, from what I've read I can't launch the main activity in the background behind a load screen.  I've tried to drop a progress bar on and also failed.

So, any suggestions?

EDIT

I'm just reading up on using an aSyncTask within a fragment.  I would love to use a progressbar, either within the slow list fragment, or on a splashscreen, or just over the main view

Comment: AsyncTask with ProgressDialog is how I would do it.

Comment: A progress bar certainly makes sense here. Also make sure you are using a background thread to do your processing, perhaps via an AsyncTask. If you have a specific problem with using a progress bar, you should include details about that here.

Comment: It is also possible to use `AsyncTaskLoader` with `DialogFragment`. For instance, check this post for a sample: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-fragments-saving-state-and-screen-rotation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
LoadTask load;

public class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

        int prog = 0;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //All your loading code goes in here 

            publishProgress(prog++); //Use this to update the progress bar

            publishProgress(-1) //Use this to open other app
            return false;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
             if(progress[i] == -1)
                 //open other app here

             for(int i = 0; i < progress; i++){
                  //set progress here with progress[i];
             }
        }


}
```

then to start the async task use

```
load = new LoadTask();
load.execute();
```

Comment: No problem :-) just comment for any more help, remember to accept if its what you wanted.